# MTP access to my phone LG-E900 (Optimus 7; Windows Phone 7.8) from Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, phone, mtp

Happy new year 2014 !

Is there a solution in order to give MTP access to LG Optimus 7 (LG-E900) from Ubuntu ? (I can see "Storage" in the Phone device on Ubuntu 13.10 but if I double-click on it, I have error message " libmtp error*: could not get object handles."

Thanks in advance for your help.

Gigi

Comment: Possibly releated: [My MTP capable device is not detected? What can I do about that?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/417323/my-mtp-capable-device-is-not-detected-what-can-i-do-about-that/417324#417324)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After looking for a solution, I installed Kubuntu 13.10 64bit. After that I ran a `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Restart and connect your device and you will see how you can do anything with it; Dolphin will do a good job with your cellphone.