# My MTP capable device is not detected? What can I do about that?

Tags: mtp

Many questions here ask for how to get a certain MTP enabled device (a phone, tablet or media player) working, assuming that the device is somehow supported by current FOSS software. But what to do if it is not?

## Problem: The device is not detected by mtp-detect

Connecting the MTP capable device to the computer and running `mtp-detect` from the [mtp-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mtp-tools/) package in terminal returns:

```
No raw devices found.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Before you start hacking…

CHECK: that the usb cable you are using is one that is used for transferring data and not just one for charging the device! Some cheap tablets and mobiles for instance only have a charging cable! To the uninitiated, they both look the same!

Please verify that `mtp-detect` really gives you the `"No raw devices found."` message. Also try to reboot and replug the device/host or use another cable that, preferably, works with another MTP enabled device, if possible.

If your device is detected, then please have a look at: [Getting MTP enabled devices to work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-enabled-devices-to-work-with-ubuntu) I also posted some troubleshooting instructions and I am still taking suggestions for improvement there.

## Installing the latest libmtp version

If you are not running the latest version of libmtp, you can:

- Search for a PPA, if you are aware of the [risks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo).
- Download the [latest libmtp release](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmtp/files/libmtp/)/[git head](http://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/code/ci/master/tree/) and compile from source. For detailed instructions see: [How can I install the latest version of libmtp?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118478/how-can-i-install-the-latest-version-of-libmtp)

## Filing a support request for your device

If compiling from source didn't work, chances are that your device is currently not supported by libmtp. A [list of supported devices](http://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/code/ci/HEAD/tree/src/music-players.h) is available which will be sourced during installation or building of the package to create `69-libmtp.rules`.

If in doubt, just follow the procedures on the [project homepage](http://libmtp.sourceforge.net/) to open a bug report/support request for adding a **new device**, it's basically running `lsusb -v`, unless you have experience in programming and submitting patches.

Note: It's useful to provide the name of your device and a link to the product page if possible. Also try searching for the device and vendor ID, you may find that the manufacturer uses the same ID for other devices and that a support request for this ID has already been filed and committed to GIT but hasn't been released a a source package or stable release. (That just happened to me with a newer Lumia device.)