# Can't sync Nokia Lumia 800 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sync, mtp, windows-phone

I am just started using Ubuntu, and i came up with some issue.

I have Nokia 800, which runs on Windows phone 7.5 and to sync my files i have to use Microsoft Zune which runs only on MAC and Windows. On Ubuntu i can not use Microsoft Zune because, i can not do anything with my file. i can not download or upload videos, audios or images. All that kind of stuff i can do only with Zune it is like iTunes for Apple devices.

How can i solve this to sync my files?

How can i connect my Nokia to laptop on Ubuntu, without Wine?

Comment: I don't think this is answerable as Windows Phones are reliant on Microsoft only tools to sync to your PC.

Comment: @NGRhodes That is not correct. That is rather FUD. Fact: Most it not all Lumia devices or Windows phones support MTP and that is supported by Linux via libmtp. If you don't like Microsoft, that's fine (and I'm probably on your side), but keep it for yourself and don't spread misinformation.

Comment: I am not spreading FUD. WP7.5 to 7.8 (possibly early, my old Lumia came with 7.5) don't support MTP (though WP8 does), hence the need to use the libmtp-zune tries to implement MTPZ (which is MTP with proprietary extensions).This lib is limited in what works, does not work between various versions of WP and Lumias.

Answer (score -1):

The Lumia 800, like many other Lumia devices, [seems to use](https://github.com/kbhomes/libmtp-zune/issues/3) **MTP** for providing access to the phone storage.

Ubuntu's filemanager does support MTP out of the box since 12.10 if I recall correctly. Also support for MTP devices improved in recent releases and with 14.04 a can finally use my Lumia 620.

**I suggest you update from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS.**

Related:

- [My MTP capable device is not detected? What can I do about that?](https://askubuntu.com/q/417323/40581)
- My answer on [Getting MTP enabled devices to work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/a/308366/40581)
- Article from WorkArounds blog: [Windows Phone 7.x on Linux](http://jaja-workarounds.blogspot.de/2012/08/windows-omnia-7x-on-linux.html)