# Cannot access contents of Nokia lumia 800

Tags: mtp, windows-phone

I have everything in place for the device. mtp-everything possible under it, and gmtp. the device mounts. But, returns error 'Could not get object handles.', when I try to access its hard disc.

Taking cues from [Can't sync Nokia Lumia 800 on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485174/cant-sync-nokia-lumia-800-on-ubuntu-12-04) , I tried to install libmtp-zune-master, but it's installation procedure has me at my wit's end.

If you need more information, please also show me how to find it from the OS.

Thank you.

edit 1 from comment by @wilf
output with phone disconnected

```
aditya@Aditya:~$ dmesg
[  640.827230] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  641.041384] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=04ec
[  641.041394] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=8, SerialNumber=9
[  641.041399] usb 1-4: Product: RM-801|NOKIA Lumia 800
[  641.041403] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 99461300-b56a-0801-4227-7d890271860b
[  656.791854] usb 1-4: usbfs: process 2902 (MtpWatchDog) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  656.956840] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  657.169866] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880049502700
[  657.169880] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880049502748
[  657.169885] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880049502790
[  657.169891] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88004b4b76c0
[  657.169896] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88004b4b7708
[  657.173537] usb 1-4: usbfs: process 2902 (MtpWatchDog) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  657.173582] usb 1-4: usbfs: process 2865 (events) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  765.872653] usb 1-4: usbfs: process 2969 (gmtp) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  766.037834] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  766.251157] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880049502700
[  766.251169] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880049502748
[  766.251175] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880049502790
[  766.251179] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88004b4b76c0
[  766.251184] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88004b4b7708
[  766.256246] usb 1-4: usbfs: process 2969 (gmtp) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  823.510150] usb 1-4: usbfs: process 2895 (qlix) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  829.289475] usb 1-4: usbfs: process 2988 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  841.439741] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  846.674691] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  846.888726] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=04ec
[  846.888737] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=8, SerialNumber=9
[  846.888742] usb 1-4: Product: RM-801|NOKIA Lumia 800
[  846.888747] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 99461300-b56a-0801-4227-7d890271860b
[ 1484.648922] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 1490.095021] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 1490.309263] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=04ec
[ 1490.309272] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=8, SerialNumber=9
[ 1490.309276] usb 1-3: Product: RM-801|NOKIA Lumia 800
[ 1490.309279] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 99461300-b56a-0801-4227-7d890271860b
[ 3983.350981] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 5
```

output with the phone connected

```
[  640.827230] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  641.041384] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=04ec
[  641.041394] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=8, SerialNumber=9
[  641.041399] usb 1-4: Product: RM-801|NOKIA Lumia 800
[  641.041403] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 99461300-b56a-0801-4227-7d890271860b
[  656.791854] usb 1-4: usbfs: process 2902 (MtpWatchDog) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  656.956840] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  657.169866] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880049502700
[  657.169880] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880049502748
[  657.169885] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880049502790
[  657.169891] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88004b4b76c0
[  657.169896] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88004b4b7708
[  657.173537] usb 1-4: usbfs: process 2902 (MtpWatchDog) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  657.173582] usb 1-4: usbfs: process 2865 (events) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  765.872653] usb 1-4: usbfs: process 2969 (gmtp) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  766.037834] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  766.251157] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880049502700
[  766.251169] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880049502748
[  766.251175] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880049502790
[  766.251179] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88004b4b76c0
[  766.251184] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88004b4b7708
[  766.256246] usb 1-4: usbfs: process 2969 (gmtp) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  823.510150] usb 1-4: usbfs: process 2895 (qlix) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  829.289475] usb 1-4: usbfs: process 2988 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  841.439741] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  846.674691] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  846.888726] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=04ec
[  846.888737] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=8, SerialNumber=9
[  846.888742] usb 1-4: Product: RM-801|NOKIA Lumia 800
[  846.888747] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 99461300-b56a-0801-4227-7d890271860b
[ 1484.648922] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 1490.095021] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 1490.309263] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=04ec
[ 1490.309272] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=8, SerialNumber=9
[ 1490.309276] usb 1-3: Product: RM-801|NOKIA Lumia 800
[ 1490.309279] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 99461300-b56a-0801-4227-7d890271860b
[ 3983.350981] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 5095.327672] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 5095.541294] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=04ec
[ 5095.541299] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=8, SerialNumber=9
[ 5095.541301] usb 1-4: Product: RM-801|NOKIA Lumia 800
[ 5095.541303] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 99461300-b56a-0801-4227-7d890271860b
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `dmesg` that appears when you put the disc in? (So *(with the phone unplugged)*, run `dmesg` and note latest output, plug the phone in and wait a little while, then run `dmesg` again and copy the new output to put into your question). Also, what did you do based on http://askubuntu.com/questions/485174/cant-sync-nokia-lumia-800-on-ubuntu-12-04?

Comment: hi @Wilf, please see the edits. Based on that link, I looked up mtpz for zune devices and downloaded a package that contained the files for installation of mtpz. The package is called 'libmtp-zune-master'. But, I could not install it.

Comment: no takers ? i know lumia 800 is an old device, but if anybody has a solution, please share