# Android Device connection problem

Tags: android, 16.10

My problem is not seeing my android device on my Ubuntu. 
Details are:

- I have Ubuntu 16.10 installed on my computer.
- I don't have any issue connecting other Usb or external HDD to my device.
- My phone is Samsung with android.
- It is already enabled MTP mode
- I cannot see my device at all event with Disks or GParted
- My phone get charged ones I connect
- I tried to change connection cable ( original ones is used)

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Does Ubuntu see it in PTP mode? Also, have you tried a different USB cable? Some USB cables don't have the data wires, and thus only work for charging...

Comment: Negative,  even in PTP mode it doesn't see.  And Yes I have tried with different cables which were working when I was using under windows 7. Thanks for quick reply @ Android Dev

Comment: Have you tried a different USB port on your computer?

Comment: May be my answer here could be useful to you: http://askubuntu.com/a/417324/40581

Comment: @Android Dev yes I tried with all 4 ports.

Comment: @LiveWireBT  mtp detect cannot find my device i tried to reboot both devices and check with my all usb cables which worked with other computers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem has been resolved.
Even I was using the original cable, (which was working fine before) it was the problem. Later on I tried to borrow some new cable from a friend and now I connected my device. 
Thanks again @Android Dev and LiveWireBT